# Field with custom schema type not getting created in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following code inside the file `user.model.js` in my **Node** + **EpxressJS** application's source.

```
"use strict";

const { ObjectId } = require("bson");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const wordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    word: { type: String, trim: true },
    match: { type: String, enum: ["exact", "startsWith", "endsWith", "contains"] }
});
const muteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    users: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    words: [{ type: wordSchema }],
    posts: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]
});
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        handle: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, unique: true },
        password: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, select: false },
        posts: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "Post", select: false }],
        favourites: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "Post", select: false }],
        following: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User", select: false }],
        followers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User", select: false }],
        muteList: { type: muteSchema, select: false },
        blockList: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User", select: false }],
        isDeactivated: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        isDeleted: { type: Boolean, default: false }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

I create a new user using the `User` model like this:

```
const user = new User({ handle: "asdf", password: "[passwordHash]" });
await user.save();
```

Now when I run `db.users.find()`, all the other fields exist in the database, except `muteList`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. I just needed to provide a default value.

```
muteList: { type: muteSchema, default: {}, select: false }
```